Material model choice
I'm trying to calibrate a specific material model using test data for a type of rubber(Treloar natural rubber), but unfortunately, my data is incomplete. I need more diverse loading cases (including different strain rates and relaxation cycles) for that material model to properly fit the tests. It can't be calibrated without adequate data. Do you know of any valuable resources where I can find various test datas for a specific material?

Build a test rig and test.

You can check: https://matweb.com/ and https://www.makeitfrom.com/ .
Those are 2 databases that include a ton of materials.
